# Export or Convert Hyper-V VM to OVA/OVF

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2012-r2, virtual-machines, hyper-v

I can't find (Google) any documentation on how to export or convert hyper-v VMs to OVA or OVF. The hyper-visor is Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard. The results from Google only point to System Center but I don't have System Center 2012.

Is there a way to export hyper-v VM to OVA or OVF? I want to import hyper-v vms to Amazon EC.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Kind of late response but I guess it might be worthy. There's no direct path on how you can achieve this but you could do the following: convert from Hyper-v to any supported VMware VMs and once you've done this then you import it into ESX, ESXi, vCenter server, VMware workstation, Fusion, or player, to name all of the possibilities. Once you have your VMs ready in any of the aforementioned hypervisors you can export any virtual machine as a template (OVA or OVF). The Hyper-v to VMware you can do it with *VMware vCenter Converter Standalone* software tool 
[Check this link](https://www.vmware.com/go/getconverter)

Comment: I'd be curious about the reliability and consistency of such tools. Is the conversion flawless or is there usually some adjustments to do? Especially thinking of unusual network configs or kernel versions. If anyone with experience doing this can comment, I'd be interested in hearing that!

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to import Hyper-V VMs directly without having to convert them first. There are two main paths: [importing the VM like you would an OVA](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/DevOps/import-windows-server-to-amazon-ec2.pdf#:%7E:text=Amazon%20Web%20Services%20%E2%80%93Import%20Windows%20Server%20to%20Amazon,you%20can%20use%20to%20run%20Amazon%20EC2%20instances.) (this guide uses PowerShell), and [Using AWS Systems Manager for Microsoft SCVMM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/scvmm-import-vm.html).